# Woocommerce, вывод атрибутов под ценой

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

По умолчанию атрибуты товара выводятся под основным фото товара, на странице товара.
Как можно изменить это расположение атрибутов, чтобы расположить под ценой товара на странице отдельного товара?  т.е. нужно выводить сбоку основного фото товара под ценой.
Какие хуки нужно использовать?
Это не работает:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', 'wc_display_product_attributes', 10 );
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_variation', 'wc_display_product_attributes',10);
```

**P.S.**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На вопрос невозможно ответить, не зная темы (каждая выводит по-своему) и не видя картинок. Общего рецепта нет.

Comment: @KAGG Design, это я тестировал на теме, установленной по умолчанию `twentynineteen`. т.е. сейчас не важно для какой темы, хотя-бы чтобы работало на теме по умолчанию. Я уже потом доработаю для конкретной темы

Comment: Вот карта хуков, должна помочь: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

Comment: и в этой теме по умолчанию атрибуты сейчас выводятся в табах

Comment: @KAGG Design, на этой карте к хуку woocommerce_after_single_product_summary привязываются и табы и описание, а описание трогать не нужно, только атрибуты

Comment: Я не думаю, что вы сможете получить ответ на свой вопрос, пока не представите понятную картинку с комментариями, где что должно быть.

Comment: @KAGG Design, добавил изображение, т.е. сейчас атрибуты выводятся в табах, нужно поместить атрибуты по цену, подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так: "тут-слаг-атрибута" это это ярлык вашего атрибута, не знаю точно но лучше если он будет латиницей (английскими символами)

```php
function display_attrib() {
    global $product;

    $attrib_unit = $product->get_attribute('тут-слаг-атрибута');

    // Выводим атрибут после цены
    if ($attrib_unit) {
        echo esc_html($attrib_unit);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_attrib', 10);
```

Comment: Попытка ответа хорошая, но вряд ли полезная через 4 года с лишним.

Comment: ой да точно, извиняюсь! XD не досмотрел
была такая проблема, при том наболевшая
странно что никто ответ здесь не оставил, думал буду первым
и все таки первый, вот только спустя почти 5 лет
"лучше поздно, чем никогда"